# find set of row, duplicate list, before insert

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table (it's a list of struct with 4 integers, first id is list id)

```
id | idL  | idA(null) | idB(null) | idC
1  |  1   |    2      |    null   |  1
2  |  1   |    4      |    null   |  1
3  |  1   |   null    |      1    |  1
4  |  2   |    2      |    null   |  1
5  |  2   |    4      |    null   |  1
6  |  3   |    6      |    null   |  1
7  |  3   |   null    |      4    |  1
```

Now I need to insert 4th list to this table

```
idA    | idB       | idC
2      |    null   |  1
4      |    null   |  1
null   |      1    |  1
```

but, it's already exist (list id = 1)

```
idA    | idB       | idC
2      |    null   |  1
4      |    null   |  1
```

alse exist (idL = 2)

```
idA    | idB       | idC
2      |    null   |  1
4      |    null   |  1
null   |      7    |  1
```

does not exist.

How to find duplicate before insert it to table

Comment: do you have the lists in a file or you are trying to insert them uing SQL Queries ?

Comment: you can delete all rows and then insert new set, if your current set is always include old rows and may have some new rows

Comment: sql query, it's a java arraylist

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be just a matter of insert from (select not in).

Try this example:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08e0f/12)

Disclaimer: In the example data you provided rows 2 and 4 got a identical idA,idB,idC set.
If that columns cannot form a unique and you already got that tuple in copy table and you need one row in copy table for each row in original table that ill be a lot harder because for a such row in copy there's no way to tell the row in original it's related.

Answer (score 0):

if values is in table temp and you know the list id.

you can use "Except"

eg:

```
insert into list (idL, idA, idB, idC)
select @list_id, t.idA, t.idB, t.idC
from
(
  select idA, idB, idC
  from @new_values
  except
  select idA, idB, idC
  from list
) t
```